# rails 3.1 simple_format html options

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Reading up here I find that I can use the simple_format text helper to send a text string to keep html newlines. Great. But I find that since it assumes a

tag that it messes with the CSS class in Blueprint CSS. OK, reading up on the API I find this:

> simple_format(text, html_options={}, options={})
>
> simple_format("I'm allowed! It's true.", {}, :sanitize =>
>   false)
>
> ## => "
>
> I'm allowed! It's true.
>
> "

There's no other example using an html_option that I can find. Here are two attempts to make it work, but both fail, either with syntax errors or app errors.

<

> %=simple_format(@opening.bob, html_options={"class="base prepend-1""},
>   :sanitize => false)  %>
>
> true)  %>

I've tried a bunch of fooling around with different combinations but due to my inexperience, I'm not hitting the right one. What am I not seeing? thanx, sam

Comment: Odd. I thought I had both best attempts showing. This is the second: <%=simple_format(@opening.bob, {class=base prepend-1}, :sanitize => true)  %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still haven't gotten this to work using html options, I failed to see the relevance of the example above it:

> simple_format("Look ma! A class!", :class => 'description')
>
> ## => "Look ma! A class!"

It was pointed out to me that this is a hash and the class indicated is a CSS attribute, not a Rails attribute.

> 'base prepend-1') %>

using my variables above.

Comment: hmm, still haven't figured why my second code is munged. This is what I meant to say: <%= simple_format(@opening.bob, :class => 'base prepend-1') %>